# How to insert data in 2 table & check if data already excist in DB in php

Tags: php, postgresql

How can I insert data in 2 tables & check if data already exists?. I'm using PHP and Postgres DB.

```
tbl_Item(ItemID-pk, Itemname, Price, $description)

tbl_Ingredient(ItemID-fk, brandname)
```

my php code on inserting(i wont paste here the rest code to keep it short) i only know how to insert using 1 table. should i make another `pg_query` for the `tbl_ingredient`?:

```
$AddItem = pg_query("SELECT INTO tbl_item VALUES ('$Itemname' ,'$Price' , '$Description'")
```

and how can I check if the data already exists? I want to check data on 3 columns.

```
$CheckItemname = pg_query("Select * From tbl_item Where itemname = '" . $ItemName);

if (pg_num_rows($CheckItemname) == 1) 
{
   alert('The Item ' . $ItemName . ' Already Exist!');
}
```

I've tried adding ( `&& (pg_num_rows($CheckHighQntyThreshold) == 1) && (pg_num_rows($CheckLowQntyThreshold) == 1) )`  but somehow adobe dreamweaver is marking it red

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I strongly suggest you to use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead of pg_* functions, since there are some security issues with these.

Yes, you need to put another query for your second table, similar to the first one.

If you want to check if the data exists, you can do something like:

```
SELECT count(*) nb_result FROM tbl_item WHERE itemname = 'your_item'
```

And then, check if nb_result > 0